# Product Review in magento 2

Tags: template, magento2.2, product-review

Magento review module(Magento/Review) consists two templates in **(Magento/Review/view/frontend/templates/helper**) folder. Those templates are **summary.phtml and summary_short.phtml.** In which scenario which template is used to display the review link. Please explain

Comment: on product view page right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic difference between summary.phtml and summary_short.phtml can be understood by below images:

**=> summary.phtml:**

[image: summary.phtml]

**=> summary_short.phtml:**

[image: summary_short.phtml]

If you need more explanation, please feel free to let me know.